# How to install react native camera without ejecting

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

React camera requires us to do linking, which with react native says we must cd into the ios folder and run pod install but we dont have the ios folder without ejecting the app, so why won’t the previous method using ‘react-native link react-native-camera’ work? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Are you using Expo? Please add information about it.

Comment: Yes using expo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using expo , then i would suggest to use expo-camera as react-native-camera wont work coz it requires linking and expo projects doesnt provide linking.

[expo-camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)

And if you are using bare react native project , then yes you have to link react-native-camera if you are using RN versions <0.60 , and if higher , it will be automatically be linked.

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

please follow this step which available in below link and i m sure it's working:->
https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/installation